# Show that the discrete metric space $(\Bbb R^2,d)$ is complete.

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

Show that the discrete metric space $(\Bbb R^2,d)$ is complete.

**attempt:**
Let $(x_n)$ be an arbitrary Cauchy sequence in $(\Bbb R^2,d)$. We want to show that $(x_n)$ is convergent in $(\Bbb R^2,d)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Since $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for any $m,n \ge N$, we have $d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$. In particular, if we take $\epsilon=\frac12$, then $d(x_n,x_m)<\frac12$ for all $m,n \ge N$. Now, since $d$ is a discrete metric, it follows that $x_n=x_m$ for any $m,n \ge N$. If we take $m=N$, then for any $n \ge N$, we have $x_n=x_N$. Notice that $x_N \in \Bbb R^2$. Then, we have $d(x_n,x_N)=0<\epsilon$ for any $n \ge N$. Hence, $(x_n)$ is convergent in $(\Bbb R^2,d)$. Thus, the discrete metric space $(\Bbb R^2,d)$ is complete, as desired. $\Box$

Does it correct? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I think, your proof is perfectly done.

Comment: Yes,it is Right